# Tomar los 2 números más altos de una lista

Tags: python

necesito sacar los 2 valores más altos de una lista que agrupa un conjunto de números

```
números = sorted({1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6})
```

En otras palabras, sacar el 5 y el 6, pensé en usar max pero creo que no es capaz de tomar 2 números

Comment: en primer lugar lo que tienes no es una lista, es un set. Luego de tenerlos ordenados escoge los 2 último (por defecto se ordena de menor a mayor). Y quita ese acento, es recomendable utilizar el alfabeto en ingles

Comment: Hola @Christian, disculpas, no sabía que era un set, no se como escoger los 2 últimos, la idea es no hacerlo manualmente, se escoger 1 solo, con Max, pero no 2, y gracias por la sugerencia del acento

Comment: Algo como esto; `números[-2:]`?

Comment: en ningún momento lo harás de forma manual, Particio ya te dio un ejemplo

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho no se si yo no entendí o formulé mal la pregunta, pero intento tomar los 2 valores más altos de ese conjunto de números, o sea, el 5 y el 6, no me funciona con eso

Comment: Esto: `numeros = sorted({1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6});numeros[-2:]` da como resultado `[5, 6]`

Comment: `sorted()` te retorna una lista ordenada de menor a mayor, `numeros[-2:]` extrae los dos últimos elementos, que en este caso serán los mayores

Comment: Ya veo @PatricioMoracho, ahora entendí, había probado poniendo `numeros[-2:] ` aparte de `numeros = sorted({1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6});numeros[-2:]` y por eso no funcionaba, ahora si, soy principiante, muchas gracias